# Jquery Datatable resize issue when there is change in header cursor

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I am using jquery datatable 1.10 for my application. My datatable definition is as follows:

```
$("#info_table", node).DataTable(
                        {
                            "dom" : 'Rflrtip',
                            "rtl" : true,
                            "paging" : true,
                            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                            "ordering" : true,
                            "searching" : true,
                            "columns" : aoColumns,
                            "fnCreatedRow" : function(nRow, aData,
                                    iDataIndex) {
                                $(nRow).attr('id', aData.ID); 
                            },
                            "language": {
                                  "emptyTable": "No records to display"
                            }
                        });
```

Issue is I need to change table thead cursor for sorting. Following CSS allow me to change the cursor.

```
#info_table th.sorting, #info_table th.sorting_asc, #info_table th.sorting_desc{
cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

But when I change cursor it doesn't allow me to re-size the column. Provide column resize option is necessary in my application. Can anyone help me to find way to re-size the column when cusor changes are made.

Comment: can u provide jsfiddle?

Comment: take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/yt3sxx4a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to use  resize column plugin for datatable.

```
<script src='http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/js/colResizable-1.5.source.js'></script>
$('#info_table').DataTable({
     customProp: 'Hello World',
    initComplete: function(settings) { 
             $('#example').colResizable({liveDrag:true});
    }
 });
```

Comment: but we can resize the datatable without even using any external js.. right? I mean I was able to resize it when i had not change table thead cursor.

Comment: yes but you need to manually handle event for column resize @PriyankaMokashi